# Divergence when spectral radius is greater than one in an iterative map.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $(M_n)$ be a convergent sequence of matrices from $\mathbb{R}^p$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$. Each element of the sequence has the same spectral radius $\sigma$, and  $\sigma\ge1$. Show that there exist an $x_0$ such that the sequence $(x_n)$ is divergent, where $x_n=M_{n-1}x_{n-1}+b$, and $b\in \mathbb{R}^p$

Any ideas? If $M_n$ is constant it can be done by making the starting point be the corresponding eigenvector to the max eigenvalue of $M$ say $x_{\lambda}$, then relying on $Mx_\lambda=\lambda x_\lambda$. But the as far as I know the eigenvector of each $M_n$ could be different, so I'm not sure how to exploit the same property.

Comment: There is certainly something missing. If $M_n=M$ for all $n$ and $M$ has an eigenvalue strictly smaller than one, you can construct a sequence $(x_n)$ which is convergent.

Comment: The sequence $(M_n)\to M$. But $M_n$ is not equal to $M$ for every $n$. I don't know if any of the eigenvalues are less than $1$ but the max eigenvalue is greater or equal to 1. Not sure why you feel it would be convergent with spectral radius $\ge 1$ ?

Comment: Or are you referring to selecting the initial condition to be a corresponding eigen vector to and eigenvalue lass than 1?.

Comment: If, say, $M_n=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&\mu^n}$ with $|\mu|<1$, $b=0$, $x_0=[0,1]^T$, then $x_n=[0,\mu^n]^T$, which obviously converges while the assumptions on $(M_n)$ are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have amended my question. I've change from " Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ is divergent", to show that there exist a $x_0$ such that $(x_n)$ is divergent.